# How to use Moq to mock a repository Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, moq

I am playing with .NET MVC at the moment and I writing some unit tests. I have an interface repository that looks like this:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
}
```

I have mocked the GetAll method like this:

```
 _mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(
            new List<Post>
                {
                    new Post { Title = "Test Post 1" }, 
                    new Post { Title = "Test Post 2" }
                }.AsQueryable());
```

Now I'm not sure how I would mock the Single method as it has a parameter that contains the expression I want to evaluate.

Thanks,

b3n

Edit:

I changed the code to:

```
_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Single(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Post, bool>>>()))
       .Returns( (Expression<Func<Post, bool>> expr) => new List<Post> { 
        new Post { PostId = 1, Title = "Test Post 1", Created = DateTime.Now }, 
        new Post { PostId = 2, Title = "Test Post 2", Created = DateTime.Now }    
        }.Where(expr));
```

But I receive the following error now:

'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments.

Is this even the best approach to do this or should the single method only return a new Post without even considering the passed in expression?

Edit 2:

This is the working result.

```
_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Single(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Post, bool>>>())).Returns(
            (Expression<Func<Post, bool>> expr) =>
            new List<Post>
                {
                    new Post { PostId = 1, Title = "Test Post 1", Created = DateTime.Now },
                    new Post { PostId = 2, Title = "Test Post 2", Created = DateTime.Now }
                }.Single(expr.Compile()));
```

Comment: Great question ... pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use an argument matcher as well as a lambda in the Returns method if you need to use the argument:

```
_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Single(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>())
               .Returns((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expr) => ... );
```

Edit:
The error you are now getting is because you are trying to pass an expression tree to LINQ-To-Objects' Where method.  To fix this, use the following:

```
_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Single(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Post, bool>>>()))
   .Returns( (Expression<Func<Post, bool>> expr) => new List<Post> { 
    new Post { PostId = 1, Title = "Test Post 1", Created = DateTime.Now }, 
    new Post { PostId = 2, Title = "Test Post 2", Created = DateTime.Now }    
    }.Where(expr.Compile()));
```

The Compile() will convert the expression tree into a simple Func delegate.  In addition, since the mocked method returns a single object, Where() will not work, either.

Comment: would it make sense to do it this way: _mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Single(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>).Returns(new Post{...});

Comment: @b3n: Yes, if you do not need the argument passed to the method to calculate the return value, then that is fine.

Comment: I actually can't get it to compile. It's complaining about the (It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>). I have replaced the TEntity with post but still does not work. This is the error I'm getting: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Post,bool>>

Comment: @b3n: I think I left out the parentheses at the end of the It.IsAny().  I've corrected my post.  You can read about argument matchers here: http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart

Comment: @Matt, thanks for correcting  the code, this fixed the issue I had before but I am still struggling. This is what it looks like now: _mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Single(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Post, bool>>>())).Returns(
                (Expression<Func<Post, bool>> expr) =>
                new List<Post>
                    {
                        new Post { PostId = 1, Title = "Test Post 1", Created = DateTime.Now },
                        new Post { PostId = 2, Title = "Test Post 2", Created = DateTime.Now }
                    }.Where(expr));

Comment: I end up getting this error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Post>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: You can compile the expr like this: expr.Compile() to get a Func to pass to LINQ-to-Objects' Where method.  In addition, that method returns a single item, so Where will not suffice. First() or Single() should be used.